# Mapbox selectAnnotation doesn't work in ViewDidLoad or first time in ViewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I have a master-detail application, and my details page is a map. When I click on the element in the Master list, the map with whole bunch of markers shows up, zooms/pans into a specific location, and an annotation pops up describing what this location is.

The implementation is pretty simple, so I thought. In my viewDidAppear, I go through the list of annotations in my mapview and just call `[mapView selectAnnotation: myAnnotation animated: FALSE]` and it works fine. BUT NOT THE FIRST TIME!

I populate my map in ViewDidLoad, and the first time the ViewDidAppear is called, the mapView.annotations array is still empty. Is there a simple way to make it work even when I first enter the details view? Or do I have to create and populate the map in the AppDelegate?

Answer (score 1):

Try using MGLMapViewDelegate and especially

```
func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(mapView: MGLMapView) {

// your code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can define a method at the DetailViewController,then when you trigger the method like tableview's didselect or prepareForSegue,you must get the DetailViewController's instance,finally,you can use this instance to call your user-defined method.

Comment: Which is pretty much saying to create a full map before coming to the map view. Makes sense